# Adding custom Class to CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I need to add a class to my CoreData model. This class has a custom class from the Heimdall Swift library (https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall) as a Member.

How can I add this custom class to my CoreDataModel?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by adding a custom class:

- If you want to add a class that represents an entity, you need to design the class so that it inherits from `NSManagedObject`. You can't add an arbitrary class as one of the entities in the data model-- the inheritance is mandatory.
- If you want to add an instance of the class as an attribute of an entity, you need to be able to convert that class to/from `NSData` so that Core Data will be able to save it. A good way to do this is to make the class conform to the `NSCoding` protocol and then use the "transformable" type for the Core Data attribute.